# splicing using text string instead of index number with Knockout.JS

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to know if there is any way to use Knockout.js to splice using a constant or text string instead of the index number?  For example, the contents of the array could change and so, I would like to use Array.splice(MyFile.specificTextString) instead of Array.splice(1) which will remove all strings in the array from index 1 onwards.

Comment: could you give an example of the text string value and how it would work? (i.e. show some code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ko.pureComputed` and `indexOf` to achieve the desired result:

```js
const dataSource = ko.observableArray(
  ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "zeta", "eta"]
);

const cutOffPoint = ko.observable("gamma");

const cutOffData = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  const index = dataSource().indexOf(cutOffPoint());
  
  return (index === -1)
    ? []
    : dataSource().slice(0, index);
});

ko.applyBindings({ dataSource, cutOffPoint, cutOffData });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(dataSource())"></pre>
<input data-bind="textInput: cutOffPoint">
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(cutOffData())"></pre>
```

Note that I'm using `slice` rather than `splice` to prevent mutating the original array.